# How can I create a Grid.ColumnDefinition in C#?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here is the code I have:

```
var column1 = new ColumnDefinition()
{
    Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)
};
var column2 = new ColumnDefinition()
{
    Width = new GridLength(30, GridUnitType.Absolute)
};

this.ColumnDefinitions.Add(column1);
this.ColumnDefinitions.Add(column2);
```

I tried to put the first definition in one line like this but it gives me an error:

```
this.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition(Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star))
```

It is saying that ColumnDefinition does not take a constructor that takes one argument.

Does anyone have any idea no how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing the terminology of constructor & initialiser. The [ColumnDefinition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.columndefinition?view=xamarin-forms#constructors) has only one constructor - the default one. On the other case, you can initialise the `Width` property from the `ColumnDefinition`'s initialiser, like you have done in the first lines of code. Basically, the initialiser invokes the default ctor and then it populates its properties with the values that you have provided.

What you can do in this case is:

```cs
this.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
```

You can read more about initialisers in C# [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers).

Answer (score 3):

the docs clearly show that [ColumnDefinition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.columndefinition?view=xamarin-forms#constructors) only has an empty constructor

```
var col = new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) };
this.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col);
```

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend using [C# Markup Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/csharp-markup?WT.mc_id=csharpmarkup-stackoverflow-bramin), introduced in [Xamarin.Forms v4.6](https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/release-notes/4.6/4.6.0?WT.mc_id=csharpmarkup-stackoverflow-bramin#c-markup-extensions).

Here's an example from my app, GitTrends: https://github.com/brminnick/GitTrends/blob/4045027a32b9eeadc3a10c5ed94df9199738cb2a/GitTrends/Views/ReferringSites/ReferringSitesDataTemplate.cs.

```cs
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Markup;
using static Xamarin.Forms.Markup.GridRowsColumns;

class CardView : Grid
{
    public CardView()
    {
        RowSpacing = 0;
        RowDefinitions = Rows.Define(
            (Row.TopPadding, AbsoluteGridLength(TopPadding)),
            (Row.Card, Star),
            (Row.BottomPadding, AbsoluteGridLength(BottomPadding)));

        ColumnDefinitions = Columns.Define(
            (Column.LeftPadding, AbsoluteGridLength(16)),
            (Column.Card, Star),
            (Column.RightPadding, AbsoluteGridLength(16)));

        Children.Add(new CardViewFrame().Row(Row.Card).Column(Column.Card));
    }

    enum Row { TopPadding, Card, BottomPadding }
    enum Column { LeftPadding, Card, RightPadding }
}
```

https://github.com/brminnick/GitTrends/blob/4045027a32b9eeadc3a10c5ed94df9199738cb2a/GitTrends/Views/ReferringSites/ReferringSitesDataTemplate.cs